# What is the best way to approach anomaly detection on a data set using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, data, anomaly-detection

I am looking to help on where to start exploring machine learning when it comes to data processing.

Say I have the following csv file with hundreds of thousands of rows of data:

| ID | Amount | Overdue (days) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,140 | 6 |
| 2 | 3,183 | 8 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Every day I read in a csv with this data. I would like a way to verify if there are any anomalies in the data before ingesting it into my database.

For example, if the days overdue column is traditionally within a range of 3-9, how can I detect if one of the rows of data actually has a day that is 150 days?

The reason I am thinking machine learning for this process is that overtime the values - ie. amount, overdue (days), etc - will change and can change significantly.

What would be the best approach to solving this problem?

Comment: What is the expected behavior when the values change significantly? Shall they then be considered outliers?

Comment: @Broele Yes, that is correct.